# FileChannel doesn't write anything

Tags: java, endianness

I have to write an integer in little endian order. So I've created a class (this class does not extend anything) with a FileChannel attribute and some write methods.

But there's a problem: only one method works, the other not!

Here is the working method (dis is the FileChannel):

```
public void writeBuffer(ByteArrayOutputStream t) throws IOException
{
    ByteBuffer buffer=ByteBuffer.wrap(t.toByteArray());
    dis.write(buffer);
}
```

And this is one of the write methods that doesn't work:

```
public void writeInt(int t) throws IOException
{
    ByteBuffer buffer=ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    buffer.putInt(t);
    dis.write(buffer);
}
```

I debugged the program and dis.write(buffer) returns 0, so what's wrong?

Does anyone know an alternative method for writing 4 byte integers in little endian?

Comment: If I recall correctly you need to [flip the buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792968). Guava has some little-endian streams.

Comment: No, I checked on the debugger and the order is correct...

Comment: [flip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip--) does not affect endianness - it switches the buffer from write to read.

Comment: Gosh! It works! But why here I have to flip the buffer and not in the writeBuffer() method?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41561964/2685581) to write data into file using FileChannel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a ByteBuffer (such as with `ByteBuffer.wrap` or `ByteBuffer.allocate`), it is created with its position at zero.  In the second method, you call `putInt`, which advances the ByteBuffer's position to 4 (the end of the buffer), so the ByteBuffer reports that there are no more bytes to read.

There are a number of methods which will reset the buffer's position.  As the comments have stated, [flip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip--) is probably the best choice, since it is specifically intended to be called when you have placed data in a buffer and want other code to start reading that data.